# Firebase "FATAL EXCEPTION: User is missing a constructor with no arguments"

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am working on an app that allows customers to book appointments and everytime I run the app, it keeps crashing and says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sakaaz.sakaaz, PID: 22041
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class edmt.dev.androidsakaaz.model.User is missing a constructor with no arguments
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zzaH(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                      at edmt.dev.androidsakaaz.SignIn$1$1.onDataChange(SignIn.java:61)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6836)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

The code doesn't have any errors and I'm quite new to android and I have no idea what to do. This is what my user.java looks like

```
public class User {
    private String Name;
    private String Password;

    public User(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public User(String name, String password) {
        Name = name;
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }


}
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? What wasn't clear to you?

Comment: I'm new to Android Studio so I know its something to do with the database but I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: The database isn't the problem. Read the error message.

Comment: User is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: Did you try creating a User constructor with no arguments?

Comment: Which Activity would it go on?

Comment: It would go in the `User` class.

Comment: Why did you upload all this code that is mostly unrelated to the error? [Edit] your question to include the User class, please. That is not an Activity

Comment: @shmosel Thank you so much, that really helped me with my project